# Neural networks in Haskell - advice

Tags: haskell, neural-network

Can anybody suggest me tutorial, book, blog or share code sample for neural networks in Haskell ? I have experience in neural networks in imperative languages, but I want try that in Haskell.

Comment: Recommending closure as off topic. This can't be definitively answered, so is better in a discussion forum, not in a Q&A.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several libraries on Hackage:

- [HaskellNN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNN) A Haskell library which uses hmatrix (and, transitively, GSL and libLBFGS C libraries) to do heavy lifting (GPL). Claims to be fast.
- [instinct](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/instinct) A pure-Haskell library which claims to be fast (BSD).
- [hnn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hnn) A minimal Haskell Neural Network Library (LGPL).
- [bindings-fann](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-fann) Bindings to FANN library.
- [hfann](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hfann) Other bindings to FANN library.

Comment: Should note that these libraries are all for *Artificial* Neural Networks (ANNs), which is indeed likely what the question was asking.  The question should be edited to add the word Artificial, as ANNs have little or no relationship to biological neural networks (the simulation of which is also a large research field).

Comment: As of writing this comment none of the mentioned libraries supports LSTM ☹

Comment: For the safe case: do not use *dnngraph*, at least not before the author make a huge refectoring. I spent ⅓ of month trying to work with it, and I can tell for sure: the author made just every possible design error that is possible to do with disregard to specific environment or lang.

Answer (score 7):

You may find this [sample application](https://github.com/mhwombat/backprop-example) useful. It uses back-propagation. I wrote an article discussing the example, explaining how the use of a functional paradigm affects the design. The article should appear in the next issue of  [The Monad Reader](http://themonadreader.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Here's the link to the Monad Reader article I mentioned: http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/issue21.pdf

Comment: That link was 404, try http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/issue214.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The DataHaskell community keeps a more up-to-date list of Hackage packages at http://www.datahaskell.org/docs/community/current-environment.html#neural-networks

As of 2019-08-26, it recommends these packages:

- [neural](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/neural) (CPU-only, see [issue 10](https://github.com/brunjlar/neural/issues/10))
- [backprop-learn](https://github.com/mstksg/backprop-learn) uses the [backprop](https://backprop.jle.im/) library (CPU-only?)
- [grenade](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grenade) (dependently typed! Comfortable API, but CPU-only so far, see [issue 55](https://github.com/HuwCampbell/grenade/issues/55) / [issue 35](https://github.com/HuwCampbell/grenade/issues/35) / [issue 6](https://github.com/HuwCampbell/grenade/issues/6))
- [hasktorch](https://github.com/hasktorch/hasktorch) (Haskell bindings to the C libs underlying PyTorch, early development but it should let you train on GPU)
- [tensorflow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tensorflow) (Haskell bindings to TF; most likely what you'd use in production, but intimidating API; can run on GPU)
- (and [sibe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sibe) (CPU-only), though under the ML heading, implements neural networks)

There's a series of blog posts on using TensorFlow from Haskell at https://mmhaskell.com/blog/2017/8/14/starting-out-with-haskell-tensor-flow / https://mmhaskell.com/blog/2017/8/21/digging-in-deep-solving-a-real-problem-with-haskell-tensor-flow etc.

If you're interested in autograd/differentiable programming, the backprop-learn author shows [how to add dependent types to a neural network](https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-1.html) and how to do [automatic differentiation (as in TF) from Haskell](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introducing-the-backprop-library.html), which is what eventually turned into the backprop library. See also the [ad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) library ([quick demo here](https://twitter.com/GabrielG439/status/647601518871359489)).